# Auto scaling text to fit within a div

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hello there I have an application that shows data in a grid fashion here is one of the "blocks" out of the grid below. Within the Divs that fill out data from a JSON file and fills the divs.

The data is limited to 4 characters (a number between 0 and 9999) for all the items. However when there is 1 character in there it looks too small because i have to keep the font size fairly small so when there is more than 1000 it doesn't overflow.

My question is what would be the best way to automatically adjust the font size for each div independently so that it always fit's at a maximum size

```
 <div class="box">
        <div class="Top">ZW01025</div>
        <div id="ZW01025" class="Midbox">
        </div>
        <div id="ZW01025b" class="Midbox">
        </div>
        <div id ="ZW01025C" class="BottomboxPercent">
        </div>
        <div id ="ZW01025D" class="BottomboxPercent">
        </div>
        <div id ="ZW01025p" class="Bottombox">
        </div>

    </div>
```

He is a fiddle of the full thing, it doesn't really fit in Js fiddle well http://jsfiddle.net/RYU54/3/

Comment: Added in to the question

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok with using a JavaScript solution I would check out flowtype.js

http://simplefocus.com/flowtype/

Answer (score 0):

Add font size in the .Top css class, lik this:

```
.Top{
    height: 20%;
    width: 90%;
    margin: 1px auto;
    background-color: #596163;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    font-size: 30px;   /* added */
    font-size: 3.5vw;  /* added */
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a script to automatically scale text to fit the surrounding div, it should work in your case:

https://github.com/jeremiahrose/perfectFit.js

Comment: This is a useful and relevant answer, why was it downvoted?